# Raspberry Pi 4 ISCSI problem

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, arm64

I have an 8Gig rpi 4b running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS that started from image `ubuntu-20.04.1-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi.img` downloaded from the web site, and blown onto a microSD via Etcher.  No problems booting or accessing.  For comparison, I have an amd64 20.04.2 LTS install in a VM on my NAS server.

My goal is to boot the rpi from an iscsi target on my NAS. There are a couple of good walk-thrus on this, but assume Raspbian, not Ubuntu.  So far the differences have been easy to reconcile.

First step seemed like it was to make sure I could attach the iscsi devices. After installing open-iscsi I do:

```
ubuntu@pi-1:~$ sudo iscsiadm --mode discovery --type sendtargets --portal 192.168.20.20
192.168.20.20:3260,1 iqn.1998-02.net.munged.nas1:pi-4-root-target
192.168.20.20:3260,1 iqn.1998-02.net.munged.nas1:pi-3-root-target
192.168.20.20:3260,1 iqn.1998-02.net.munged.nas1:pi-2-root-target
192.168.20.20:3260,1 iqn.1998-02.net.munged.nas1:pi-1-root-target
```

Then:

```
ubuntu@pi-1:~$ sudo iscsiadm --mode node --portal 192.168.20.20 --login --targetname iqn.1998-02.net.munged.nas1:pi-1-root-target
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.1998-02.net.munged.nas1:pi-1-root-target, portal: 192.168.20.20,3260] (multiple)
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.1998-02.net.munged.nas1:pi-1-root-target, portal: 192.168.20.20,3260] successful.
```

I do the exact same commands on the VM, and i get a new /dev/sdb device.  I get nothing on the rpi itself.  I was expecting an /dev/sda or something under /dev/mapper, maybe.  I am careful not to try this on the rpi while the target is attached to the VM.

```
ubuntu@pi-1:~$ lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE   LABEL       UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0                                                                              
├─mmcblk0p1 vfat     system-boot B726-57E2                               134M    47% /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 ext4     writable    483efb12-d682-4daf-9b34-6e2f774b56f7   11.1G    18% /
```

and:

```
ubuntu@pi-1:~$ ls -al /dev/disk/by-id
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  13 Apr  1  2020 mmc-SC16G_0xc3294085 -> ../../mmcblk0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Apr  1  2020 mmc-SC16G_0xc3294085-part1 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Feb  3 06:37 mmc-SC16G_0xc3294085-part2 -> ../../mmcblk0p2
```

and:

```
ubuntu@pi-1:~$ ls -al /dev/mapper
crw-------  1 root root 10, 236 Apr  1  2020 control
```

And dmesg shows only:

```
[40782.442776] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[40782.482588] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
[40879.580046] scsi host0: iSCSI Initiator over TCP/IP
```

On the VM, dmesg shows the device actually being attached and such.

I've verified that the initiator `iscsid.service` is loaded, active, and running.

First question is what's next in troubleshooting this.  I'm at the raw limits of my knowledge on this.

Second question I guess I need to ask, is would my experience be any different if I installed Ubuntu via the rpi imager program, rather than just using a downloaded image?

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd covered all the bases on this, but I forgot a step on setting up the NAS side.  I hadn't associated any extents to the target, so there was nothing for the rpi to connect to devices.

Once I'd associated `pi-1-target` to `pi-1-extent`, it worked perfectly, creating /dev/sda.

Sorry for the PEBCAK.